# Possible responses when retrieving the domain's product version - Google Apps Admin Settings API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

What are all the possible responses when retrieving the domain's product version?

Response example:

```
<apps:property name='edition' value='standard' />
```

I'm using this Google Apps Admin SDK: [Retrieving the domain's product version docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_domains_product_version)

I can only identify two response values:

- `standard`: legacy free edition
- `premier`: bussines edition

Answer (score 1):

I only see this [reference](https://github.com/twilio/howtos/blob/master/intercom/gdata/apps/adminsettings/service.py) for the Edition property.

Returns: A string, the domain's edition (premier, education, partner)

Hope that helps!

Comment: education is also a possible value for Google Apps for EDU domains.

Comment: A search in my DB gives me: | appsless   |
| education  |
| government |
| isp        |
| ispPremier |
| premier    |
| standard   |

Comment: @qtxo do you know what "appsless" is for?